# "With you" vs "For You"

Tags: word-usage

1. Hi Willis, I have a question for you.
2. Hi Willis, I have a question with you.

What is the difference?

Comment: The first one is perfectly straightforward - I have a question I want to ask Willis. But I am struggling to understand what the second one means. Perhaps I left a written question with him/her two weeks ago, and I still haven't had a reply.

Comment: Thanks WS2. Your comment makes sense and answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, the second one is ambiguous, incomplete or incorrect. The first one is by far the only acceptable of the two.